# Eclipse 3.8.1 Content Assist causes computer to hang for ~ 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, content-assist

in Eclipse 3.8.1 with basic JDT (1.3.2) for JavaScript editing, on bigger projects, initiating code completion (`Ctrl + Space`) causes Eclipse to hang for about 5 seconds while the CPU us maxed out.

Whatever it is doing, I want to disable it. It's annoying to wait every time I just want to insert a simple template. Is this possible?

Also, the Content Assist auto activation trigger is set as `.` (dot). But whenever I enter a dot, it just lists my templates that start with a dot, and not all of them. What does this setting do? I still need to press Ctrl+Space to see all my templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the **Window** → **Preferences** menu item, and then select **Content Assist** under **Javascript** → **Editor** in the left hand tree menu you can deselect the **Enable auto activation** checkbox (Basically right above the Content Assist auto activation trigger that you mentioned in your question)

You can also change the behaviour of content assist under the following preferences page (changing/removing some of the `Proposals` might improve the delay):
[image]

Comment: This doesn't stop the 5 second pause when I `Ctrl+Space` on purpose.

Comment: Are you saying that because you have a habit of hitting ctrl+space you want to disable content assist when you hit that combination and only for JavaScript files?

Comment: You might be able to reduce the delay by removing/changing the proposal options (edited above).

Comment: I am saying that I want to be able to use ctrl+space without the delay. It's like it's 'building' my entire project just because I hit ctrl+space for a template. Disabling other proposals helps a lot, so I upvoted your answer. But ideally, I would like to have project-based proposals too, and it shouldn't have to load 5 seconds because the entire project is already in memory, every function and method is already in the `Outline` window. It feels like it does some unnecessary processing that could be turned off. But I'm not sure what's happening under the hood.